# CakePHP requestAction returned data with find('all') order query not working?

Tags: sorting, cakephp, element

I do not know why my DESC sort query is not working?? According to the manual and other sources, it should be working fine:

```
function pd_list() {

    return $this->PlanDetail->find('all', array('order' => 'PlanDetail.name DESC', 'limit' => 10));

}
```

All data is being displayed as expected in my element, but its not in DESC (and the 10 limit is not working either) order and Ive tried several tests and the 'order' => seems to have no effect?

Comment: Try setting the `order` setting as an array. `'order' => array('PlanDetail.name DESC')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joeb,

Wow. After all the hair I lost, I did not try that (and now the sort is working!) : ) .. Here is my completed working function:

```
function pd_list() {
    return $this->PlanDetail->find('all',
    array('contain' => false,
    'group' => 'PlanDetail.name',
    'order' => array('PlanDetail.name ASC'),
    'fields' => array('id','name')));
}
```